# Style BasedOn breaks when x:key is added

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have user control which define custom style for the telerik's control `RadTreeViewItem`. The problem is that when I don't have x:key there isn't any errors but when I add the x:key property I've got error "`The resource "RadTreeViewItemStyle" could not be resolved.`"

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="MySuperGoodStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadTreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadTreeViewItemStyle}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

In runtime there isn't any problems, the style works fine as expected so it looks like design only error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this before :

```
  <Style TargetType="telerik:RadTreeViewItem" x:Key="RadTreeViewItemStyle">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeviewFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1 4 5 4"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="24"/>
        <Setter Property="IsDropAllowed" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="telerik:DragDropManager.TouchDragTrigger" Value="TapAndHold"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemDefaultTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <telerik:TreeViewPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and be sure to have in your header :

```
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it gave me error again. 
Anyway it looks like the bug fixes itself maybe it was bug in the VS and after restart it was fixed. I will give you best answer because you tried.